# Java while loop printing squared numbers can't use int?

Tags: java, types, do-while

In Java, create a do-while loop that starts at 2, and displays the number squared on each line while the number is less than 1,000,000. And this is what I have:

```
int k = 2;
do {
    System.out.println(k);
    k *= k;
} while(k < 1000000);
```

The problem is the output, somehow it is getting stuck at 0 and infinitely looping through 0 to print those out? I don't believe it is due to the fact that the number is out of int range, since a 32 bit number's range is around +/- 2 billion... But when I switch up the data type of k to be long everything works fine... Why is this?

Comment: Your code prints powers of 2, not squares.  Those grow very fast.

Comment: Are you trying to print all squares? In which case you can't use your output as input. Instead have a separate variable that increments and print its square.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really is due to `int`. The sequence produced this way is

```
2
4
16
256
65536
0
```

And then it remains zero. Note that it never rises above 1000000.

With a `long`, the number after 65536 would be 4294967296 (which does not fit in an `int`, but does fit in a `long`), so it stops.

This is perhaps more obvious in hexadecimal, the sequence then reads (with sufficiently long integers)

```
2
4
0x10
0x100
0x10000
0x100000000
```

An `int` can only keep the lowest 8 hexadecimal digits, so 0x100000000 becomes 0.

Comment: Thank you, didn't think about how it checks 65536^2. You're right that does indeed exceed the int range.

Answer (score 0):

Your code to print squares should be

```
int k = 2;
do {
    System.out.println(k*k);
    k++;
}while(k < 1000000);
```

As you are storing the result in same variable, your output is growing exponentially

Comment: I think there may be a misunderstanding, I do want to print the result  squared. harold explained it correctly, thank you though!